# How to configure a Logitech USB headset on Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, usb

I have a Logitech USB headset [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003NREDG4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003NREDG4) 
but I can't hear anything nor input anything through it.
I am working on a Fedora 14 desktop.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                  HDA Intel at 0xfebdc000 irq 51
2 [Headset        ]: USB-Audio - Logitech USB Headset
                  Logitech Logitech USB Headset at usb-0000:00:1d.0-2, full speed

/sbin/lsmod | grep -c snd
14

lsusb
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c529 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 046d:0a0b Logitech, Inc. ClearChat Pro USB
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Please advise

Comment: Please read our FAQ next time? what does this have to do with Servers eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get it working. On gnome-Fedora once can use Phonon settings, and push up the priority of the media source and output.
By default the Intel HDA was topmost, and hence the headset was not working.

Answer (score 0):

That headset doesn't list Fedora as a supproted oerating system.

So you're probably not going to get it working since there's [no Fedora drivers offered by Logitech](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/438/7115?section=downloads&WT.ac=sc|downloads||dd).